# Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código

Tags: discusión

Soy un poco nuevo en esto de la programación y en este foro. ¿Qué puedo hacer si requiero formular una pregunta, pero necesito poner mas código que explicación para que la gente pueda entender mejor mi problema?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta va en Meta. No es necesario poner todo el código, ni siquiera es necesario poner el código real. Existe lo que se llama "reproducir el problema", esto es, crear en un ambiente controlado (y aislado) de variables, bucles y funcionalidad necesaria para que el código llegue al inconveniente, sin incluir lo que si trabaja bien. Eso es justo lo que necesitamos.

Comment: Mientras más reduzcas tu código, mayores son las probabilidades de obtener respuesta. Por una parte demuestras esfuerzo en aislar el problema y haras más fácil trabajar en él.

Comment: Imagina que publicas una pregunta sobre poo en donde creas 10 clases de 100 lineas (una es moto, otra es auto, otra es tren, etc). Y resulta que tu error es "ocurre x fallo cuando hago una subclase de Vehiculo". Si ese es el fallo, no necesitamos conocer tooooodas las subclases de vehiculo, solo una. Y harías gastar tiempo y esfuerzo a la persona para aislar el problema y trabajar con él (como dice Candid Moe). Además, quizá hay partes de tu código en las cuales hace falta ciertas cosas (como archivos externos al script o modulos adicionales) que no tienen nada de relación con el problema.

Comment: Todo exceso o carencia es malo. Lo mejor, es crear un código "especial" que solo contenga lo escencial para reducir el problema. Esto es un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Subir un mcve en lugar de mucho código de más, es la solución al problema.